# Cannot add a search provider in IE 11 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Just installed Windows 7 x64 and I'm trying to change my default search provider and I cannot.

I thought it might have been a Google thing but I cannot ANY search provider.

JavaScript is working and this is a clean install. Doesn't matter if I go here: http://www.iegallery.com/en-au/Addons/Details/813 or http://www.google.com/homepage/search/sp-ie10.html Nothing happens. A box is suppose to popup asking me but it never shows.

Ive also tried thru F12 changing my document mode but nothing...

Answer (score 2):

This is a [widely reported problem](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2917819/patch-management/microsoft-admits-stealthy-re-release-of-patch-kb-3038314.html) after installing the April update for Internet Explorer KB3038314.

Comment: Intresting. In case it was something like that, I already have started to format and reinstall. Probably was as I updated everything.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cog wheel on the top right and go to 'Manage add ons". Then follow the steps on the picture.

[image]

Then you can select from all those.

[image]

Comment: Wow, first time seeing somebody actually use High Contrast.

Comment: Yeah, I have to use high contrast. I have only 40% vision. Macular degeneration. There is nothing much you can do other than shots into the eyes every 6 weeks - no fun.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I already tried this and nothing. I hit the Google Search, add and nothing happens.